# Access tabs directly in Safari with ⌘+1..9 keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: safari, shortcut

Can you access tabs directly in Safari using the ⌘+1..9 shortcuts like Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now the default behavior of Safari 9.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, but why 'sadly'? I like it, and there's a toggle for it in Preferences for those who don't.

Comment: @grgarside I removed the word "sadly" since it does not contribute to a correct answer. But I prefer the prior behavior greatly, thus my use of the word "sadly".

Comment: This makes me sooooooooo happy. Safari is screaming fast and now it behaves properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer pre-dates Safari 9.0 where Apple correct the Cmd-# behaviour.

You can, but it takes an extension to be able to do it.

You'll need to install [Safari Tab Switching by Olivier Poitrey](http://hackemist.com/SafariTabSwitching/) to be able to use ⌘+1..9 to access tabs directly. It's a great extension if, like me, you've got these shortcuts in muscle memory from working with Google Chrome for so many years now. It's also [open source and available on GitHub](https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching) for the curious.